# Uploading Files to AWS S3 from an Android App

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**Edited 7th June,14**

My Android app needs to have a feature where clients can **upload their files**. I want **AWS S3** as my storage. Moreover i dont want to use **SECRET_KEY** and **ACCESS_KEY_ID** on client side. What is the the best way to do this. Can someone provide the working code too ?

I read that i can request to AWS for a signed URL and then make client directly upload to that URL. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can call AWS APIs in step 4.
[image]

And please check the [AWS STS(Security Token Service) document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/Welcome.html), "Ways to Get Temporary Security Credentials" section.